# How can I fetch an image from a URL returned from the Unsplash API?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

```
import requests


def linkFetch():
    url = "https://api.unsplash.com/photos/random/?client_id=MyAccessKey"

    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.json()["urls"]["raw"]
    return data


def imageFetch(data):
    print(data)

imageFetch(linkFetch())
```

Here my code runs and fetches a url for an image but how can I automatically open the photo in small window. the linkFetch() function actually gets the image link and I want imageFetch() to actually open the photo. I'm new to using apis so any help will be useful. I already tried using another request.get() but I may have used it incorrectly. Other solutions seem to want to download the image indefinitely where I want to just open it.

Note: MyAccessKey replaces my actual key

Comment: You can look into GUI frameworks for Python. Python already comes built-in with Tkinter to do this. An alternative is to use the [Pillow](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/) library to open in your default viewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to first get the image data by sending a request then pass it to the [pillow package](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) to display the image.

```
from io import BytesIO

from PIL import Image
import requests

img_url = imageFetch(linkFetch())
response = requests.get(img_url)
img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
img.show()
```

Comment: The last line is returning an error "cannot identify image file "